# pyDrake import Error: cannot import name 'DrakeVisualizer', ClippingRange, DepthRange, et al

Tags: drake

I am using the latest pydrake docker image and trying to visualize some of my results. Everything else in pydrake imports and works really well. Specifically packages in the pydrake.geometry cannot be imported correctly for some reason. I need to use a number of methods related to DepthRenderCamera. Another colleague is able to import everything just fine in the same setup. The code is similar to the the pydrake tutorial here. https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/robotlocomotion-drake-qtseq8o3/notebooks/tutorials/rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb
Any pointers or help is appreciated!

from pydrake.geometry.render import (
ClippingRange,
DepthRange,
DepthRenderCamera,
RenderCameraCore,
RenderLabel,
MakeRenderEngineVtk,
RenderEngineVtkParams,
)

Comment: Howdy John! Your usage is a tad unclear, so unfortunately it's a tad hard to figure out what the underlying issue was. I am able to run the notebook on Binder as well, I assume like your colleague. Unfortunately, the notebook link you supplied above is invalid, as only you can access it, so I can't see your changes. Can you download the code you updated (from Jupyter Notebook: `File > Download as > Notebook`), post it to https://gist.github.com/, and link that here?

Comment: Also helpful: In your notebook, can you post the output of `!cat /opt/drake/share/doc/drake/VERSION.TXT` from your Binder notebook? (From mine: `20210215074611 ec9080a51d212f916538a622962a2b723154fc1b`)

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric! I am literally having trouble importing those packages in my docker container. The import statements were copied from rendering_multibody_plant.ipynb tutorial. I just need to access depthCamera and DrakeVisualizer packages and for some reason, they just won't import. https://gist.github.com/John-Z-Zhang/d211431a95150a11a794e98993717a07. My Version output is 20201013064707 e44eb6af9b0286a0c4c0e04e06fbfc945e9afe49. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClippingRange` binding wasn't added to pydrake until:

```
commit 9b7a97b302214002a320088761b4d76196503618
Author: Eric Cousineau <eric.cousineau@tri.global>
Date:   Wed Oct 21 18:24:51 2020 -0400
```

Your 20201013064707 revision is too old (2020-10-13).